# Setting values to each items in a list of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I'm trying to programmatically set a values to each item in a list inside a nested dictionary.

for example, let's say my initial dictionary, which I constructed is:

```
    {'Abraham': {'subjects': ['Chem', 'Bio', 'Phy', 'Math']}}
```

Given some lists of values:

```
assess_type = ['Quiz', 'HW', 'ATTND', 'Exam']

chem = ['127', '135', '17', '46']
bio = ['154', '64', '14', '54']
phy = ['115', '115', '15', '55']
math = ['140', '160', '20', '40']
```

And I want to achieve a result like this:

```
    {'Abraham': {'subjects': [
     'Chem': {'Quiz': '127', 'HW': '135', 'ATTND': '17', 'Exam': '46'},
     'Bio': {'Quiz': '154', 'HW': '64', 'ATTND': '14', 'Exam': '54'} ,
     'Phy': {'Quiz': '115', 'HW': '115', 'ATTND': '15', 'Exam': '55'},
     'Math': {'Quiz': '140', 'HW': '160', 'ATTND': '20', 'Exam': '40'}
      ]}}
```

I can construct the dictionary itself, but where I am having issues is how to set the values programmatically.
how do I index into the list inside the dictionary and set the value like that programmatically if I just have a list of values as written above?

Comment: This can be done using `map`. It would be helpful to learn it as it makes your life easier, and does what you're asking for efficiently. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

Comment: i think the scrutur that you expected is not supported in python. you cannot have key value pairs in list

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dict(zip(keys, values)** to create the dictionary based on the given list:

```
assess_type = ['Quiz', 'HW', 'ATTND', 'Exam']
chem = ['127', '135', '17', '46']
```

then for chem will be `chem = dict(zip(assess_type, chem))`
the result will be `{'Quiz': '127', 'HW': '135', 'ATTND': '17', 'Exam': '46'}`

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to make data aligned to each other like this
if '`subjects': ['Chem', 'Bio', 'Phy', 'Math']` strings are in the Title case then the variables carrying the values should be in the Title case to make it comparable during using `eval()` function below

let's say we have student

```
student = {"Abraham": {"subjects": ["Chem", "Bio", "Phy", "Math"]}}
```

Then we have assessment type

```
assess_type = ["Quiz", "HW", "ATTND", "Exam"]
```

These are the values that should be zipped to each subject in assess_type order

```
Chem = ["127", "135", "17", "46"]
Bio = ["154", "64", "14", "54"]
Phy = ["115", "115", "15", "55"]
Math = ["140", "160", "20", "40"]
```

Now we will loop through the student dict and then subjects

```
for key, value in student.items():
    # Loops through the dictionary and gets the values
    for sub in value["subjects"]:
        # Loops through the list of subjects and gets the values of the subjects in the list of subjects

        student[key][sub] = dict(
            zip(assess_type, eval(sub))
        )  # Enzips the list of subjects and the list of values
```

Then if we print the student:

```
{'Abraham': {'subjects': ['Chem', 'Bio', 'Phy', 'Math'], 'Chem': {'Quiz': '127', 'HW': '135', 'ATTND': '17', 'Exam': '46'}, 'Bio': {'Quiz': '154', 'HW': '64', 'ATTND': '14', 'Exam': '54'}, 'Phy': {'Quiz': '115', 'HW': '115', 'ATTND': '15', 'Exam': '55'}, 'Math': {'Quiz': '140', 'HW': '160', 'ATTND': '20', 'Exam': '40'}}}
```

Now you will be able to modify the output structure after that with a little effort.

So, in the loop, The `eval()` method parses the expression passed to this method and runs the python expression (code) within the program.

The `zip()` function takes iterables (can be zero or more), aggregates them in a tuple, and returns it.

For better understanding please google these terms to get an idea whats is happening in the loop.